# PHP Spreadsheet - Column visible

Tags: php, spreadsheet

I have an Excel document with a lot of hidden columns that I don't want to process in a script that uses the [Spreadsheet PHP library][1]. I am trying to get if a column is visible or not with the getColumnDimension($col)->getVisible() function.

Prior to the code sample, I create the worksheet1 object and get the maximum number of columns to loop through like this:

```
for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col){    
    // Column is visible?
       if($worksheet1->getColumnDimension($col)->getVisible()){
           $worksheet2->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, 'Col: '.$col.' Visible');
       }else{
           $worksheet2->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, 1, 'Col: '.$col.' Not Visible');
    }
}
```

The result is always 1 even when the columns are hidden.

Of course I have tested that I loop through the columns correctly.

I've spent hours reviewing documentation and code and I can't figure out why.

I have done the same test hiding rows and in that case it returns 1 or empty.
[1]: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation (https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Worksheet-Worksheet.html#method_getColumnDimension) `getColumnDimension()` requires string index of the column eg: 'A':

```
public getColumnDimension(string $column) : ColumnDimension
```

you using numeric index so you should try `getColumnDimensionByColumn()`

```
public getColumnDimensionByColumn(int $columnIndex) : ColumnDimension
```

Try this:

```
for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {    
    // Column is visible?
    if ($worksheet1->getColumnDimensionByColumn($col)->getVisible()) {
        $worksheet2->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, 'Col: '.$col.' Visible');
    } else {
        $worksheet2->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, 1, 'Col: '.$col.' Not Visible');
    }
}
```